# Lock screen cycles on and off

Tags: 18.04, lock-screen

I have my Ubuntu 18.04 desktop computer set to lock the screen and show a blank screen after 10 minutes of inactivity. After 10 minutes, here's what actually happens:

1. The screen goes black, and the monitor turns off (good)
2. A while (maybe 5-10 minutes), the monitor comes back on
3. The lock screen is displayed for perhaps 30 seconds
4. goto 1 and continue this infinite loop

I'd really like the screen to just stay black until I touch the keyboard or mouse.

Any ideas for what might be going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Is some other event happening in the meantime like an email being received? That will cause a brief interruption to the blank screen.

Comment: @Graham I closed all applications and disabled notifications. The problem persists.